# How to inject PesistenceContext in my tests using EJB 3.1?

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

Hi in Spring it's easy to do so... as Spring doesn't require an Container, you just add an @autowired and it's done.

But in EJB 3.1, using @Inject is useless if the app is not deployed... I am getting nullpointer and it's looks logical to get them, because of the lack of a container during tests.

How can I inject a PersistenceContext into my **TESTS** for example using only EJB 3.1 features ? is it possible without a container ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Arquillian project. It allows outside container testing of Java EE applications.

http://www.jboss.org/arquillian

Comment: Hum... nice that looks promising, I will defininetly give it a try. But I would like it even better if I could do that without anymore dependencies.

Comment: @cfontes at least it's just a testing dependency. The deployed application does not need to know about it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Glassfish 3.x will allow you to embed the container and run your tests. Here's a few links that should get you going:

- [Unit Testing EJBs and JPA with Embeddable GlassFish](http://ctpjava.blogspot.com/2009/10/unit-testing-ejbs-and-jpa-with.html)
- [JPA Unit testing with the GlassFish 3 embedded EJB container](http://www.blackbit.be/2010/02/17/jpa-unit-testing-with-the-glassfish-3-embedded-ejb-container/)
- [Adam Bien's Weblog](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/embedding_glassfish_v3_in_unit)